# Name of an equivalence identity on sums of weighted binomial coefficients

Tags: reference-request, binomial-coefficients

In my research, I have encountered the following equivalence identity:

> For $a,b,n\in \mathbb{N}$, the equivalence
>   $$
> \left({\sum_{0\leq w < b}n^w}\right)^a \substack{\equiv\\n^b} \sum_{0\leq w < b}{a-1+w\choose w} n^w
> $$
>   holds.

One way of proving this equivalence relation is by induction on $b$;  it seems to be elementary identity, and I am guessing that it has already been encountered.

> **Question**: Does the above identity have an established name?

References welcome.

Comment: I can imagine an induction on a. The induction on f puzzles me greatly. One place to try is Wilf's generatingfunctionology .  Gerhard "Or Does F Equal A?" Paseman, 2018.03.05.

Comment: A typo indeed; I was thinking induction on $b$, but perhaps an inductive argument on $a$ also suffices.

Comment: I'm sure induction on $a$ or $b$ are possible, but note that the left hand side is a power of a geometric series. Modulo $n^b$, the left hand side is $(\sum_{0 \leq w} n^w)^a = (1-n^w)^{-a}$, which has a well-known expansion, see Wilf's generatingfunctionology (https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf) as Gerhard says, or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Generalizations .